# Grammar-kit tutorial? .bnf and .flex file instrcution?

Tags: grammar-kit

I'm doing a plugin for other language, with Grammar-Kit. -> https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit
I'm not sure what .bnf and .flex files are responsible for? From my view, .bnf defines how operations in this language looks like: eg. assign value as (a = 1) formate. What about .flex file ?